# How does the quantum Fisher information provide bounds for the estimation of output states?

Tags: quantum-state, state-tomography, quantum-fisher-information

Assume you have some **quantum process** $Q$ (e.g. quantum state tomography) that intakes initialised states $\rho_{i}$, $i=1,\ldots,n$ and gives some output $\rho'_i$.
$$
\rho_1 \to Q \to \rho'_1 \\
\rho_3 \to Q \to \rho'_2 \\
\vdots \\
\rho_n \to Q \to \rho'_n
$$
Then, assume we can estimate these outputs using some method and we produce estimates $\hat \rho_i$.
$$
\hat \rho_1 \text{ estimates } \rho'_1 \\
\hat \rho_2 \text{ estimates } \rho'_2 \\
\vdots \\
\hat \rho_n \text{ estimates } \rho'_n \\
$$
How can I use the notion of the **Quantum Fisher Information** for finding bounds on how well these output states $\rho'_i$ can be estimated by my methods? E.g. if the density matrix formed by the initial states corresponds to that of a qubit ($n=4)$:
$$
\rho = \sum_{i=1}^{4} \lambda_i |i\rangle \langle i | = \sum_{i=1}^{4} \lambda_i \rho_i.
$$
In this case, do I need to compute  $F_Q[\rho,\hat\rho]$? If so, how is this done? System can be closed for simplicity so that evolution is unitary.